# WPF Adding a ListViewItem (not a class I made) to a listview

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, colors, background

Until now, I added items to my listview using

```
lstView.Items.Add(new MyData("Val", 1));
```

The problem is that I cant change that item's style (such as background) simply with items[i].Background.

I tried making MyData inherit ListViewItem but then the binding doesnt work.

My binding :

```
<GridViewColumn Header="my var" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Name}" />
```

as I said thing line works when I add the item as my own class but not when my class inherits listviewitem. I also tried adding a listviewitem with DataContext of my class with no luck.

Anyone has any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

WPF has the concept of [Data Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx) to separate the visualization from the underlying data. A ListView (as any other ItemsControl) provides data templating for its items by means of the [`ItemTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemtemplate.aspx) property. You can read about that in [Styling and Templating an ItemsControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742521.aspx#DataTemplating_ItemsControl).

Given this simple DataItem class

```
public class DataItem
{
    public string ItemText { get; set; }
    public Brush ItemBackground { get; set; }
}
```

a very simple DataTemplate for that class may contain just a Border and a TextBlock control:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="{Binding ItemBackground}">
                <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

In a ListView with a GridView, you would specify the [`CellTemplate`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridviewcolumn.celltemplate.aspx) of a GridViewColumn instead of the `ItemTemplate`:

```
<ListView Name="listView">
    <ListView.View>
        <GridView>
            <GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Border Background="{Binding ItemBackground}">
                            <TextBlock Margin="4" Text="{Binding ItemText}"/>
                        </Border>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn>
        </GridView>
    </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

Now you could simply add DataItems to the ListView like this:

```
listView.Items.Add(new DataItem { ItemText = "Item 1", ItemBackground = Brushes.AliceBlue });
listView.Items.Add(new DataItem { ItemText = "Item 2", ItemBackground = Brushes.LemonChiffon });
listView.Items.Add(new DataItem { ItemText = "Item 3", ItemBackground = Brushes.LightCoral });
```

In order to make the UI react on changes of the DataItem object, the DataItem class would have to implement the [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms133020.aspx).

```
public class DataItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    ...
}
```

To get an even better separation of data and UI you would not add items directly to the `Items` collection of the ListView, but instead bind the [`ItemsSource`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx) property to a property of type `ObservableCollection<DataItem>`:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding DataItems}">
    ...
</ListView>
```

You may read more about this topic in [Data Binding Overview / Binding to Collections](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752347.aspx#binding_to_collections).

Answer (score 0):

You can use databinding, and for each item, associate a property such as BackColor to the item, bind the item (into ObservableCollection), and if you want to change the color, simple call item.BackColor=..., this will do!

Comment: Lets say I had a property backcolor in MyData class. To what do I bind it in the xaml? Cant bind it to listviewitem since ut doednt exist yet